# como deletar os valores da calculadora após concluir a operação? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, html5

fiz um modelo de calculadora baseado em um vídeo no youtube para um trabalho escolar, mas nesse vídeo ele não mostra como reiniciar a calculadora depois que ela dá o resultado. por exemplo, faço a soma de 10+10 e ela retorna 20, mas quando vou começar outra operação o 20 continua aparecendo na tela.

**javascript:**

```
function inserir(x){
    var y = document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = y + x;
 }

 function zerar(){
     document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "";
 }

 function deletar(){
    var del = document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = del.substring(0, del.length -1);
 }
 function result(){
    var result = document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML; 
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = eval(result);
    
 }
```

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="calculadora">
            <p id="resultado"></p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('(')">(</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir(')')">)</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="zerar()">C</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="deletar()">Del</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('7')">7</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('8')">8</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('9')">9</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('/')">÷</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('4')">4 </button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('5')">5</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('6')">6</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('*')">x</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('1')">1</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('2')">2</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('3')">3</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('-')">-</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('0')">0</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('.')">.</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="result()">=</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="inserir('+')">+</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, loiyuz! Você pode chamar a função zerar() se um resultado já estiver sendo apresentado na tela quando a função inserir é chamada.
Para verificar se já existe um resultado na tela você pode usar uma variável booleana que guarda true (para verdadeiro) e false (para falso). Fazendo assim:

```
var resultadoEmTela = false;
    function inserir(x) {
        if(resultadoEmTela==true){
            zerar();
            resultadoEmTela = false;
        }
        var y = document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = y + x;
    }

    function zerar() {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "";
    }

    function deletar() {
        var del = document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = del.substring(0, del.length - 1);
    }
    function result() {
        var result = document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = eval(result);
        resultadoEmTela = true;
    }
```

Como pode ver, a variável resultadoEmTela inicia com o valor false. Quando um resultado é inserido na tela a variável recebe o valor true. E então, quando o usuário vai inserir um número novamente é verificado se o resultadoEmTela é true, ou seja, se já existe um valor na tela. Se sim, ele chama sua função zerar() e então deixar a variável resultadoEmTela como false, para que o processo possa se repetir outras vezes.

Comment: muito obrigado, cara! você me salvou de verdade. @GusFerreiras

Comment: Nada, @loiyuz! Um prazer ajudar!